# One sample data with unusual structure, permutation test?

Tags: skewness, permutation

I have N sets, each of them consisting of 1000 integer values. Typically, more than 90 %  of values within a set is zero, thus median is zero. The nonzero elements are positive integers. We take N values, one from each distribution. How to test if the chosen values are significantly higher than if they were taken at random?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be enough information here to formulate a good answer.  Could you tell us more about what the underlying statistical problem or application is?

Comment: Imagine we have designed a random number chooser robot and we want to test if he is working properly and not biased to choosing higher numbers.

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't help. The experiment you propose simply provides inadequate information for addressing your question, unless you add some (strong) assumptions about how the distributions in the sets might be related to one another.

Comment: The sets are completely independent of each other.

Comment: Then your program is hopeless.

Comment: Why, dont understand, can you please clarify, maybe there is some misunderstanding